# By mapping the generators $s_{i}$ into $S_{n}$ appropriately, find a well-defined epimorphism $\theta :G_{n}\rightarrow S_{n}$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

So $G_{n}$ is the group with presentation

$\left<s_{1},...,s_{n-1}\mid s_{i}^{2}=1, s_{i}s_{j}=s_{j}s_{i} \text{ if } \left | i-j \right |\geq 2, s_{i}s_{j}s_{i}=s_{j}s_{i}s_{j} \text{ if } \left | i-j \right |=1\right>$.

What is a good way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you think of any elements of $S_n$ that act like the $s_i$ here? They are involutions, they commute if they are "far enough apart," etc.

Comment: For future references, $G_n$ is called the *Braid* group. Make some drawings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
\begin{align} 
\theta: \ & G_{n} \to S_{n}\\
& s_i \longmapsto (i,i+1) \tag{1}
\end{align}

The mapping defined in (1) is an isomorphism.